# MariaDB: Why is LOCATE using case sensitive comparison?

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a database with the following data in the "Name" column:

[image]

However, running the following query returns incorrect results:

```
SELECT `e`.`Id`, `e`.`Name`
      FROM `Regions` AS `e`
      WHERE (LOCATE('s', `e`.`Name`) > 0)
```

Returns:

```
Calgary Northeast
Test Location
Calgary West
```

However its not returning "Southern BC" which has an `s` at the beginning. According to the MariaDB docs, the `LOCATE` function is case-insensitive (see: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/locate/), so I would expect "Southern BC" and "Calgary South" to show in the results. It's clear my query is doing a case sensitive comparison but I don't know why. All of my collations are set to `utf8mb4_general_ci` everywhere I have checked.

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA
    , TABLE_NAME
    , TABLE_COLLATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME ='Regions';
```

returns `utf8mb4_general_ci`

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
```

returns

```
collation_connection    utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_database  utf8mb4_general_ci
collation_server    utf8mb4_general_ci
```

I'm running `10.3.10-MariaDB-1:10.3.10+maria~bionic-log`

Any idea on this behavior?

Comment: Please setup a https://dbfiddle.uk/ ; select mariadb 10.3 from the list in the top left corner. It will help in debugging. Something about the table structure may have been missed. Maybe the charset to be used at the time of making database connection is set to binary.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either

```
SELECT `e`.`Id`, `e`.`Name`
      FROM `Regions` AS `e`
      WHERE (LOCATE('s', `e`.`Name`) > 0) OR (LOCATE('S', `e`.`Name`) > 0)
```

OR

```
SELECT `e`.`Id`, `e`.`Name`
          FROM `Regions` AS `e`
          WHERE e.name like '%S%' or e.name like '%s%'
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce the problem:

```sql
MariaDB [_]> SELECT VERSION();
+-----------------+
| VERSION()       |
+-----------------+
| 10.3.10-MariaDB |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                    |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.002 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'collation%';
+----------------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name        | Value              |
+----------------------+--------------------+
| collation_connection | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_database   | utf8mb4_general_ci |
| collation_server     | utf8mb4_general_ci |
+----------------------+--------------------+
3 rows in set (0.001 sec)

MariaDB [_]> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Regions`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.005 sec)

MariaDB [_]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Regions` (
    ->   `Name` VARCHAR(255)
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.010 sec)

MariaDB [_]> INSERT INTO `Regions`
    -> VALUES
    ->   ('Calgary South'),
    ->   ('Calgary Northeast'),
    ->   ('Calgary Location'),
    ->   ('Location'),
    ->   ('Calgary West'),
    ->   ('Calgary BC'),
    ->   ('Southern BC');
Query OK, 7 rows affected (0.004 sec)
Records: 7  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [_]> SELECT `Name`
    -> FROM `Regions`;
+-------------------+
| Name              |
+-------------------+
| Calgary South     |
| Calgary Northeast |
| Calgary Location  |
| Location          |
| Calgary West      |
| Calgary BC        |
| Southern BC       |
+-------------------+
7 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [_]> SELECT `Name`
    -> FROM `Regions`
    -> WHERE LOCATE('s', `Name`) > 0;
+-------------------+
| Name              |
+-------------------+
| Calgary South     |
| Calgary Northeast |
| Calgary West      |
| Southern BC       |
+-------------------+
4 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  The collation of `name` is significant.

If you are using the default collation or some other `..._ci` collation, then this is suitable:

```
WHERE e.name LIKE '%s%'
```

to catch uppercase and lowercase `s`.

`LIKE` and `REGEXP` are appropriate for checking for substrings.  `LOCATE` is appropriate for finding the position of something in a string.